# comparing products of builds in release

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, build-process

I need to compare build outputs of VS2005 in order to be sure I can reproduce the exact same product.

when I do two builds one after the other in release and compare the produced files I get different files, doing text comparison it seems that more than just the datetime is different

how can I build in order to reproduce exact same product each time ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you build, the compiler embeds:

- The date and time
- A GUID (used for debugging etc, I believe)
- Potentially the assembly version (which may have "1.2.3.*" and populated automatically)
- Potentially a strong hash

A couple of options:

- Find out where the files are "known to differ immaterially", wipe those bytes, and then compare
- Use ildasm to convert the assemblies to text, and then compare those results. (I haven't checked whether or not this reveals the differences too - it may do, in which case again you'd have to explicitly ignore certain sections)

This problem does pop up every so often, so I'll see if I can come up with a tool to do the comparisons - although it's unlikely to cope with signed assemblies, as the location of the signature could vary significantly.

Answer (score 0):

One question: you did ***text*** comparison for binary build outputs? 
As I know most of compilers never produces binary identical build output for the same project. Compiler encodes into binary time of compilation, special ordinal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use DumpBin to do binary comparisons of different builds that ignore the per-build variations.  See [How to compare binary images of the same project builds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164151). The article says it applies only up to Visual Studio 6, so I am not sure it will work for 2005 or beyond..

Comment: In VS 2010, the dumpbin tool exists, but running it on two subsequent builds of a dll produced numerous differences.