# Visual C++ 2010: deterministic build? How to diff exe/dll files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, diff

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Deterministic builds under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180852/deterministic-builds-under-windows)
>   [comparing products of builds in release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319864/comparing-products-of-builds-in-release)

Is a Visual Studio 2010 C++ build deterministic?  That is, will it always produce the same binary instructions given equivalent source code input and identical compile/link settings?

I appreciate there may be various date stamps and other compile-system-dependent fields that get written to the binary EXE or DLL file.  So the second part of my question is: how can I ignore these "mutable" elements when `diff`ing such files?

I'm trying to create a tool that will compare binary artifacts from different build iterations and tell me if they are functionally equivalent or not.

Comment: see these questiosns  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319864/comparing-products-of-builds-in-release
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180852/deterministic-builds-under-windows
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832783/compare-two-dlls

Comment: Technically, this is not an _exact_ duplicate because the original question was about VS2005 and this is about VS2010.  In theory, the answers could be different.  In practice, I don't think they are, but I don't have any data to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip additional information like timestamps with the dumpbin command. Try

```
dumpbin /rawdata
```